# When I SAW the top of it, I HAD shivers(tenses confusion)

Tags: tense

I was watching a Youtube video of a doctor removing a splinter stuck on a patient's right foot, inner side a few minutes ago. Fortunately, he successfully removed the splinter and he said:

> ''When I **SAW** the top of it(splinter), I **HAD** shivers.

As far as I know, HAD preceded PAST TENSES when you are storytelling about past events right?

So this means that, the doctor HAD shivers(that soon?) BEFORE he even SAW the top of the splinter stuck on the foot?

Should it be as soon as he HAD seen the top of it, he GOT shivers?

Comment: No. You are confusing the use of the past form of *HAVE* = *had* as a primary verb meaning "possessed, experienced" with the use of the same past form as an auxiliary with a past participle of the primary verb to create a past perfect construction.

Comment: Oh that's why.... nice! Good thing I have asked this, or else I think I wouldn't be able to spot that by myself. I thought HAD is only for verbs... anyway, iI get it. Hehe thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case'shivers is a noun, not a verb, so the verbs 'saw' and 'had' are both in the simple past tense (from 'see' and 'have'). As a consequence they can occur at the same point in time, so 'had' does not imply something occurring before 'saw' occurs. 'Had' is not a part of the past perfect tense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw the top of the splinter, it gave me shivers or the shivers. Or: I got the shivers. Or: I had the shivers.

Both things happened in the simple past.

However, one should remember that the language police are not present for every statement a person makes. In any event, his seeing the top of the splinter resulted in shivers right afterwards. So, simple past is fine.

I have shivers now.
I had shivers then.

When I see blood, I get the shivers.
When I saw blood [in the  past], I got or had (the) shivers.

Those are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thx, but can I ask why do you have to put a definite article ''the'' in shivers? Should it be just shivers...

Comment: 'Shivers' is the plural of 'shiver' which is a countable noun. As a plural countable noun 'shivers' can be used with or without the definite article in front of it, (e.g.  'That sound always gives me the shivers' and 'That sound sends shivers down my spine.'). When used with tenses of 'have' or 'give' it is more common to use the definite article, i.e. 'it give me/you/him the shivers' is much more common than 'it give me/you/her shivers', although 'I/you/him have/has the shivers' is only just more common than 'I/you/her have/has shivers'.

Comment: @James As far as I know, when you put a word in parenthesis as I did, it means the expression can take or not take the article "the". Therefore, I have already explained, basically, all that. In any event, the question was focused on the verb tense more than the shivers aspect...also, you didn't even bother to mention that part of the sentence, so......

Comment: @Lambie I agree that, in this and other forums,  when a word is contained within parentheses it usually indicates that the word is optional. My previous comment was solely in response to John Arvin's comment, not to your answer. John's comment asked for further information regarding the use of the definite article before 'shivers', which is what I provided. As both of us had already responded to his original question regarding tenses I saw no reason to provide further commentary on that topic.